# how to work with ls command with a variable value?

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to create a script to list the folders inside **tmp1/test/**. when i am using **source** in ls command it not working. getting output like **main.sh: line 4: tmp1/test/: Is a directory**. any help???

```
source="tmp1/test/"
dest= "tmp2/" 

ls -F ${source} | grep '/' | awk -F'/' '{print$1}' > directories.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `source= 'tmp1/test/'` failed is a little complicated, but it goes like this.  A space is a token separator in Bash, and each token is expanded in turn (that's simplified):

`source=`         Creates an empty variable called "source" just for this statement

`'tmp1/test/'`    is the name of a command which uses the "source" variable

Of course, `tmp1/test/` is not a command or external program, hence the error message.  So the bottom line is **don't put spaces around an = in an assignment**.

Here is an alternative which is pure bash and does not rely  on external programs like `ls(1)`, `grep(1)` and `awk(1)`:

```
source='tmp1/test/'
dest='tmp2/'     # NO spaces around = allowed 

# The * gets all the filenames
for fname in "$source/*"
do
    # The -d tests if it is a directory
    if [[ -d $fname ]]
    then
        echo "$fname"
    fi
# This redirects all standard output in the loop
done > directories.txt
```

There is a difference with your solution.  If there is a symbolic link to a directory `ls -F` puts a `@` at the end, not a `/`, so your solution will miss those.  My solution includes them, but symbolic links to directories are uncommon, although I use them on OS X.

A more concise (but arguably less readable) version of the loop could be:

```
for fname in "$source/*"
do
    [[ -d $fname ]] && echo "$fname"
done > directories.txt
```

BTW, you can avoid the `grep` in your solution with:

```
ls -F "$source" | awk -F'/' '/\/$/{print $1}'
```

Note the quotes around `"$source"` in case the directory name contains embedded whitespace (the `{ }` have no effect in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I used single quotes ans removed the space after **source=**. Now its working...

```
source='tmp1/test/'
dest= 'tmp2/' 

ls -F ${source} | grep '/' | awk -F'/' '{print$1}' > directories.txt
```